# Is it possible to set where condition to hbase row-keys?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Is it possible to set where condition to hbase row-keys? Suppose I have row-keys 1,2,3,4,5...
I need to query like "where row-key<4"??

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an InclusiveStopFilter

```
s = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes("startRow"));
s.setFilter(new InclusiveStopFilter(Bytes.toBytes("stopRow")));
```

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/branches/0.90/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/InclusiveStopFilter.java

Comment: OK, but here also I need to know the start row and end row right? What about setting 'where row-key>4', something like that?

Comment: if you don't set a start row it starts at the beginning.  If you don't set a stop row, it goes to the end.

Comment: OK fine, What about if I am fetching a row and it consists of thousands of columns and i want to limit the column value count?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own FilterBase implementation with any meaning you want. 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/branches/0.90/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterBase.java
override filterRowKey method like in InclusiveStopFilter sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a scan start and stop row:

```
Scan s = new Scan();

s.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes("startRow"));
s.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes("endRow"));
```